# how to get context in to other class

Tags: android

i have `public class ExperimentAllInOneActivity extends Activity implements    OnClickListener` on each button click listener i want to go some other class like `public class TemperatureStrategy` and perform all logic calculation in this class but main thing is that i have class like `public class DialogDisplay extends Dialog implements OnItemSelectedListener` in this class a custom dialog is created. Now I have question is that on each button onclick listener I want to call(display) this custom dialog class in, spinner class and like that type of element, and all logic performed with class TemperatureStrategy. How to build constor and pass context of all class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it in 2 ways AFAIK:

**1.** Add a `context argument` in your function like this:

public static void display (Context context) {
// Do your action using action...

**2.** Add a `context argument to your class constructure` and use this context in all your functions.

Answer (score 1):

If your onClickListeners are declared inside the Activity (I suppose they are), then you can call getApplicationContext() anywhere inside the Activity class, as opposed to use the 'this' keyword that would refer to the onClickListener itself.

Comment: This is the best and the cleanest way!

Answer (score 0):

You can place the context in the .Tag property that you pass into your button event and pull it back out.